# Pyspark - How to explode un-equal length json to columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, I have a dataframe with different length of non-nested json:
And for each json, I have about 200 keys. So it's not possible to use `pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object`.

```
id, json(string format)
1, {‘a’: 1, ‘b’:2, ‘c’:3, ...}
2, {‘a’: 1, ‘b’:2, ... }
3, {‘a’: 1 , ‘c’:3, ... }
```

I want to explode it to:

```
id, a, b, c
1, 1, 2, 3
2, 1, 2, null
3, 1, null, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I forgot to mention, I have about 200 keys. So it's not possible to use get_json_object() I think.

Comment: then use `from_json` if you know their DataType. for example: `schema = 'struct<a:int,c:int,b:int>'`, then use `F.from_json('json', schema)`. missing keys should be filled with null.